# How to extract values from HTML tags with VBA to use in Excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

The snippet summary: (first li-tag is open to show the content, other li-tags are the same, only with different values in dd-tags.

```html
<body id=“WEBSITE“>
 <div> id="layout" class="  MAIN SECTION "</div>
  <main>
  <ul id=“RESULTS“>
  <li class="content" style="position:relative;">
  <dl>
   <dt class="first">HEAD01:</dt>
   <dd>VALUE01</dd>
   <dt class="first"> HEAD02:</dt>
   <dd> VALUE02</dd>
   <dt class="first"> HEAD03:</dt>
   <dd> VALUE03</dd>
   <dt class="first"> HEAD04:</dt>
   <dd> VALUE04</dd>
  </dl>
 </li>
<li class="content" style="position:relative;">… </li>
 <li class="content" style="position:relative;">… </li>
 <li class="content" style="position:relative;">… </li>
 <li class="content" style="position:relative;">… </li>
</ul>
</main>
</body>
```

The **li-tags** contain different properties of one object each with same headers HEAD01, 02, 03 and 04 (under "dt"), the VALUEs are different in each li-tag (under "dd"). I don't succeed in extracting the VALUEs in  tags in such a way that they are listed in Excel as column values under the corresponding header, i.e. Value01 from all li.dd-tags under HEAD01 in the Excel table.

My code:

```
Public Sub GetData()

    Const url = "URL"
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim RecsCnt As Object, x As Long
       
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
                                   
     Set RecsCnt = html.querySelectorAll("li")
    'Set RecsCnt = html.querySelectorAll("dl")
    
    With ActiveSheet

       For x = 0 To RecsCnt.Length - 1
        .Cells(x + 2, 2) = html.querySelectorAll("dd").Item(0).innerText
       Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Does anyone have an efficient idea? THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If html is as shown, you will get faster results using id and class; you can retrieve headers and chain nextSibling to move to adjacent element. Please note: this is set-up to run for headers + 1 row. If there are more please update html to reflect this.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()

    Const URL = "URL"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, x As Long
       
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With html.querySelectorAll("#RESULTS .first")
        
        For x = 0 To .Length - 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, x + 1) = .Item(x).innerText
            ActiveSheet.Cells(2, x + 1) = .Item(x).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is always more effective than mine, I will replace...thanks! And by the way, I started to really like your tip: https://regex101.com/r/WAJqAh/1 ... has already helped me very far!

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the data you need - you just need to play around with formatting:

```
Sub Get_Text_from_website()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://versteigerungspool.de/amtsgericht/celle.92437/suche"
    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Dim j As Long
    Dim element As Object, i As Long
    Set dtElements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("dt")
    Set ddElements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("dd")

    For Each element In dtElements
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = element.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next

    For Each element In ddElements
        ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 2) = element.innerText
        j = j + 1
    Next

    IE.Quit
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you for your goodwill, but I have already been there myself and the results are not the ones I have shown in the Excel image above. With your code, I get repetitions of HEAD01,02, 03 and again HEAD01,02, 03 etc all in the first column (A) and all VALUES are under each other in the 2nd column (B)! Playing around with formatting will not solve the problem easily

Comment: Can you paste the expected result with real values from the website as I think I don't fully understand your expected result.